# Swift _ABSearchComparison is not convertible to ABSearchComparison

Tags: macos, swift

Hi I am very new to programming and Swift and I am stuck with the search of the Address Book.

I get this error: _ABSearchComparison is not convertible to ABSearchComparison

```
var adbk = ABAddressBook.sharedAddressBook()

var isGroupBusiness = ABGroup.searchElementForProperty(kABGroupNameProperty, label: nil, key: nil, value: "Business", comparison: kABEqual)
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kABEqual` has the type `struct _ABSearchComparison` and must therefore
by converted explicitly to an `ABSearchComparison` (aka `CFIndex`),
as expected by the `comparison:` parameter:

```
var isGroupBusiness = ABGroup.searchElementForProperty(kABGroupNameProperty,
            label: nil, key: nil, value: "Business",
            comparison: ABSearchComparison(kABEqual.rawValue))
```

Comment: Note that in Xcode7/Swift2 the enum value is obtained with .rawValue rather than .value

Comment: @GuillaumeLaurent: You are completely right. I have fixed it now, thanks!